# Test location.reload on DeviceOrientationEvent

Tags: javascript, jquery, sinon, qunit

I have a function, which triggers a site reload, when orientation of device is changed

```
function readyFunction() {   
if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {window.addEventListener('orientationchange', function () { location.reload(); }, false); }
}
```

I want to test, if the function works correctly, using qunit.js and sinon.js. Therefore, I built the following test:

```
QUnit.test("On 'orientationchange' reload triggered", function (assert) {

    var spy = sinon.spy(readyFunction);

    $(window).trigger('orientationchange', function (e) {
        switch (window.orientation) {
            case 0:
                //portrait mode
                break;
            case 90:
                //turned to the right
                break;
        }
    });

    assert.deepEqual(spy.callCount, 1, "Two reloads triggered");
});
```

As you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/65bq6/3/ the result is  null, though one reload should have taken place.

Does anyone know, how to refactor this code?

Comment: It would make far more sense to use CSS media queries to optimise your UI for landscape/portrait displays.

Comment: I already use a css grid.system in combination with media.queries. This function serves to set the correct viewport after device orientation changes.